# Перехват HTTPS с помощью сниффера HttpAnalyzer

Tags: https

Возникла проблема с перехватом защищённого трафика с помощью этого HttpAnalyzer, HTTP ловит без проблем, HTTPS в IE тоже отслеживает, но в Firefox нет. При этом браузер выбрасывает предупреждение о незащищённом соединении. Но это не основная проблема, у меня есть девайс (iPhone), который зацеплен к интернету через прокси на моей локальной машине (FreeProxy). Трафик с девайса я тоже сниффаю без проблем, пока дело не касается HTTPS, а он тоже мне нужен. Два дня бьюсь над проблемой, поиск ничего не дал, но, может быть я не там ищу. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Меня задолбали глюки HttpAnalyzer и я перешел на Fiddler. Без проблем расшифровывает HTTPS трафик в браузерах и в приложениях, в которых можно прописать прокси.
Есть инструкция по настройке iPhone http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForiOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема перехвата трафика https с iPhone решается установкой сертификата на девайс. Достаточно загрузить файл сертификата и открыть его. После согласия на установку, система установит его и safari покажет весь свой трафик, ну или почти весь). Трафик с поиска гугла не ловится, с википедии тоже, может ещё что-то. Остальное работает. 
А вот с хромом (тоже iOS)  проблема, так и не разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, с программой идет сертификат, если не ошибаюсь файл имеет расширение .der . Если установить его в Firefox (Настройка->Дополнительные->Сертификаты->Импортировать), то и его трафик будет перехватываться. Насчет iPhone, вам вероятно так же требуется установить в него сертификат HttpAnalyzer. Я перехватывал трафик из Firefox, но к сожалению не работал с iPhone.